# Canvas Element Disabling

Tags: jquery, html, css, canvas, three.js

I am working on a project using Three.js with a menu on top of the canvas element (plain old div) but the canvas element receives input when clicking or scrolling the div. Is there anyway to temporarily disable the canvas or all mouse interactions with it.

currently I've found:

```
$('.submenu').on("mouseenter", function(event){
    $("#canvas").css("pointer-events", "none");
});

$('.submenu').on("mouseleave", function(event){
    $("#canvas").css("pointer-events", "");
});
```

but this doesn't seem to have any effect on it, I've also searched for quite some time and can't find a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which browser & version are you using...pointer-events was implemented relatively recently

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$('.submenu').mousedown (function (event) { event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation(); });
```

Comment: This didn't have any effect on the problem either.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found a solution, by adding a boolean to the above mentioned code and then using it as an indicator of whether the focus is on the div or the canvas, I am able to use that in the event handlers as a condition for the operation. Not exactly what I had in mind but it works rather well.